# Python NetworkX find a subgraph in a Directed Graph from a node as root

Tags: python, graph, networkx, directed-graph

I am writing a code to extract information from a directed graph. This graph has cycles as well. For example,

```
A->B->C->D
A->E->F->A
B->F->G
```

From this graph, I want to create a sub graph or the list of the nodes, where the input would be any node, and output would be the graph where the input node is the root, or the list of the nodes that has all the child nodes ( till the end of the graph ) from the input nodes

For example, in the above example, 
1. If the input node is C, the output would be D
2. If the input node is B, the output node would be C,D,F,G,A ( Since there is a cycle, which makes A to B bidirectional )
3. If the input is G, the output is blank or null.

Is there any functionality in python networkx, that I can use to solve this problem ?

Alternatively, is there any other tool that can help me solve this problem ?

Comment: How can the output be C,D,F,G,A if the input is B? Shouldn't it be only C and D?

Comment: @Swailem95 .. B is dependent on C and D ( 1st line ). B is dependent on F and G ( 3rd line ) , F is dependent on A ( 2nd line ) . It should actually be C,D,F,G,A, E .. I missed that.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is the function [`dfs_preorder_nodes()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_preorder_nodes.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.depth_first_search.dfs_preorder_nodes). Here is a little demo based on your data:

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()

g.add_edge('A', 'B')
g.add_edge('B', 'C')
g.add_edge('C', 'D')

g.add_edge('A', 'E')
g.add_edge('E', 'F')
g.add_edge('F', 'A')

g.add_edge('B', 'F')
g.add_edge('F', 'G')

print('A:', list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(g, 'A')))
print('B:', list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(g, 'B')))
print('G:', list(nx.dfs_preorder_nodes(g, 'G')))
```

Output:

```
A: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'E']
B: ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'A', 'E', 'G']
G: ['G']
```

The output includes the starting node. Therefore, if you don't want it, just remove the first element from the list.

Note that `dfs_preorder_nodes()` returns a generator object. That is why I called `list()` to get usable output.

Comment: Thanks so much !! I tried bfs_tree() and dfs_tree() functions , but this one looks better !

Answer (score 4):

`nx.ego_graph()` does exactly what you describe. Using the example given by @Hai Vu:

```
g = nx.DiGraph()

g.add_edge('A', 'B')
g.add_edge('B', 'C')
g.add_edge('C', 'D')
g.add_edge('A', 'E')
g.add_edge('E', 'F')
g.add_edge('F', 'A')
g.add_edge('B', 'F')
g.add_edge('F', 'G')

a = nx.ego_graph(g, 'A', radius=100)
a.node
#out: NodeView(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'))

list(nx.ego_graph(g, 'G', radius=100).node)
#out: ['G']
```

`radius` should be an arbitrarily large number if you would like to get all nodes in the tree until the leafs.