# how to extract all sub-graphs containing a specified node from a directed graph

Tags: python, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, subgraph

I have a directed tree, where some of the nodes have branches. The tree does not have any cycles.

As an example, say a tree like:

```
a -> b -> c
     |
     d -> e -> f
```

I want to find all possible sub-graphs which contain the root node. 
Following are the sub-graphs in this toy example:

```
a -> b -> c 
a -> b -> d -> e -> f
```

How should I extract these sub-graphs using code?

Is there any well-known algorithm which finds this? Or will this need to be done using some custom-built code?

I found the following link: [Python NetworkX find a subgraph in a Directed Graph from a node as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47892944/python-networkx-find-a-subgraph-in-a-directed-graph-from-a-node-as-root?rq=1)
but it outputs all the nodes in the sub-graphs when the required node is specified, and not the individual sub-graphs which I require.

Please suggest, as I am new to python.

Comment: Try looping through and specifying all leaf nodes.

Comment: That's not every possible subgraph. You want every path from root to leaf. Consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134742/python-yield-all-paths-from-leaves-to-root-in-a-tree